# MSSQL database still hits the 10GB limit after enabling RBS

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint

So i am new to the whole sharepoint/mssql thing, but i have managed to install sharepoint 2013 foundation, all is on one server (default installation) and i have RBS setup. Everything goes to the fileshare. For every document that i upload i see new files beeing created as it’s supposed to do.

However, after migrating a bunch of sites i noticed the database is also reaching 9.44GB??

I have tried to find an answer as to why this happens, but documents on the technet site are not ones i seem to grasp.

Is there anyone that can explain to me how this works, and possibly why the database keeps folling up?? I have followed a few RBS tutorials, they are all the same so i am pretty sure i set it up correctly :)

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use a SQL Server Express edition that does not have the limitation?

Comment: That was my initial message as well :-) unfortunatly, its a small company with a small budget. Someone else advised them to go the RBS route.

Comment: SQL Server Express 2017 does not have a database size limit.

Comment: @GregAskew unfortunately that seems to be incorrect: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2017-editions also, from what i gather Sharepoint 2013 doesn't support SQL 2017. i guess someone higher up the company has to make some choices :)

Comment: The database size limit for SQL Server Express 2017 is 524 Petabytes. What's to support? It just needs a database. You could set the COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL if that were really an issue.

Comment: @GregAskewplease see: https://docs.microsoft.com/nl-nl/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-2017 under Scale section it clearly says "Maximum relational database size 10GB" for Advanched Express and Express, so where do you get that the database size limit for Express is 524Petabytes?? :)

Comment: Yep, my bad sorry.